# Is it better to ask or not send a thank you?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, communication

Recently, a friend had a Skype interview where they, unfortunately, did not catch the interviewer's name, though it was mentioned once at the beginning of the interview.  The area is medicine, and this is an interview for residency.

The Skype name used was not personalized, so we were unable to glean the gentleman's name from any profile data.

Would it be more appropriate to not send a thank you letter or should they e-mail the program coordinator seeking that information in order to write a thank you letter with this information?  Which way would be less unprofessional?

Comment: there is little reason this was downvoted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Thank You is always appropriate.  Since there is a way to get the name and contact information, your friend should take advantage of it.

A good Thank You note is short, honest, and perhaps makes mention of something important about the candidate that you want to remind the interviewer about.

Keep it simple and short, don't sound desperate or creepy. :-)

And a hand-written, snail-mailed note is a really nice touch that will set you apart.

Comment: also i think it is sweet and endearing to go to the effort to send a thankyou note. it will show your friend is considerate, which is a plus in the medical field

Answer (score 0):

If you are going through all this trouble just to send a thank you note, it's probably not worth it - You're wasting time writing it and he'll be wasting his time reading it.

If, however, you are sending him a thank you note, you are thanking him for his time and for giving a good impression of his program, AND if he has any questions for you or requests to you, to feel free to contact you immediately, then going through the trouble of sending the thank you note is definitely worth it. And it's definitely worth it if you have an ulterior motive to pick his brains about the program.

Don't say thank you just for the sake of saying thank you - I personally would hate getting buried under from hundreds of thank you notes.